# Using For Loop in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

in objective c , I am trying to move the highlighter through 2 paralleled boxes together one by one, when I press Play button (using alpha)
(every box has array from 8 pictures)

the problem is only one of the boxes pictures is being highlighted. while, the other one is only highlighted after the first one is finished. I don't know if the problem from the using of for loop ? or something else.

```
 - (IBAction)didPressPlay:(id)sender {

    self.playing = YES;
    self.timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0/self.BPM target:self selector:@selector(timerFire:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
 }

 - (void) timerFire:(NSTimer *)timer {

    for (UIButton *button in self.trackOneButtons) {

        if (button.tag == self.sampleNumber) {

            button.alpha=1.0;
        }
        else {
            button.alpha = .5;
        }

        for (UIButton *button in self.trackTwoButtons) {
            if (button.tag == self.sampleNumber) {
                button.alpha=1.0;
            }
            else {
                button.alpha =0.5;
            }
        }
    }

    self.sampleNumber ++;
    if (self.sampleNumber >7) {
        self.sampleNumber = 0;
    }
 }
```

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns here, where more information will be needed for any one to help. That said, one of the best ways to debug any loop is to step through it in the debugger. Set a breakpoint at the start of timerFire, and step through while observing the values of button.tag.

Comment: In other way, how can I use two for-loop to work together (first member of first for-loop with first-member of second for-loop ), then second member of the two for-loops works together and so on.

Comment: Well, I think lousy indentation and formatting may be a big part of the problem.

Comment: And it would help if you explained what your two arrays of buttons are.  And explain what this means: "the problem is only one of the boxes pictures is being highlighted. while, the other one is only highlighted after the first one is finished."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming both arrays will always have the same count, you can try changing your loop to this:

```
- (void) timerFire:(NSTimer *)timer {

    CGFloat sampleNum = self.sampleNumber;

    void (^alphaAdjust)(UIView*) = ^void(UIView*button){
        if (button.tag == sampleNum){
            button.alpha=1.0;
        } else {
            button.alpha =.5;
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i!=self.trackOneButtons.count; i++) {

        UIView *btn1 = self.trackOneButtons[i];
        alphaAdjust(btn1);
        UIView *btn2 = self.trackTwoButtons[i];
        alphaAdjust(btn2);
    }
...
}
```